# Javascript, ajax extract data from website

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I am trying to do a web application with PhoneGap so I´m using web language such as Javascript and HTML5 and CSS3. I have a google map API so I want to populate several coordinate points and some real-time information from the website.

The code I have so far is the following:

```
    function initialize() {
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.940937, -3.191612),
     // center: {lat: -28, lng: 137}
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    });

     function getResults(){ 
                var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
                var data = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
                var results = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += headers.length) { 
                    var item = {};
                    for(var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) { 
                        item[ headers[j].textContent.trim() ] = data[i + j].textContent.trim(); 
                    }
                    results.push(item);
                };
                return results;
            }
            console.log(getResults());
            jsonString = JSON.stringify(getResults());
    function callback(results, status) {
            if(status == google.maps.places.PlaceServiceStatus.OK){
             for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){

             var place = results[i];
             console.log(place.name);
             console.log(place.value);
             console.log(types[0]);
             createMarker(results[i]);

             }
            }
            }

    setInterval(function($.ajax({ 
       url: "http://edinburgh.cdmf.info/public/carparks/list.htm?callback", 
        data: getResults(),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        //add_header: Acess-Control-Allow-Origin *
        success: function(data){
            //Update the script
             script.setValue(data.value);},
        error: function() {alert('Failed');},
        beforeSend: setHeader           
        });
        ,30000)
       function setHeader(xhr){
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', results);
          }
        var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);
  }
```

AND the HTML

```
 </head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <h1>Welcome to SmartParking</h1>
<div id="map"></div> 

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=198X7G-KU3xan5zrG0EtQ63Guojo" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

So basically the getResults() method would go to the website tablesorter and extract the td information into a JSON file.

I am quite novice on web technologies and really do not know if I can do it in this way as I keep having the empty arrays with an error.

I have tried the GetResuts function on the actual website element Inspector console [Console answer to getResults()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5PCs.png)and it works it gives me back the Object Array with all the information

[screenshot problem on console Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4PEm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is restructure your code.

First, you need to create `<form>` element in your HTML [like so.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp)

Next, you have to set up a server. Whenever you call an API and get back data, it should be handled on the server, NOT on the front-end as you are doing. Basically, you will send the form data to the backend, the backend sends api call with that data, and returns the api data to the front end.

Finally, if you want real time updates, you do not want to setInterval the ajax call— this is a pretty common mistake, actually, read about it [here](https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery). The link also describes "comet polling" (which facebook uses) but you should really think about using some sort of Websockets connection, such as socket.io with Node.js, which is very easy to set up.

Best of luck!